# Joint probability of dependent random variables

Tags: normal-distribution, joint-distribution

I am not sure the following derivation is correct

Let $Y \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$, $\theta \sim N(\mu_\theta, \sigma_\theta^2)$, and $x=y\theta$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, the joint pdf is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x|y)f_{Y}(y)$

, where $f_{X}(x|y)=N(y \cdot u_\theta, (\sqrt{y \cdot \mu_\theta} )^2)$, referred to $x=y\theta$, and $f_{Y}(y) = N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2) $.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: You need apply the change of variable formula from $(y,\theta)$ to $(y,x)$, the Jacobian being$$\left|\frac{\text d(y,\theta)}{\text d(y,x)}\right|=|y|$$

Comment: Presumably you are assuming $Y$ and $\theta$ are independent

Comment: Alternatively, use $x=((y+\theta)^2-(y-\theta)^2)/4,$ which is manifestly a difference of correlated non-central $\chi^2(1)$ variables. I think this might be the quickest way to see how messy the result is.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.